# Best way to query Individuals from an Inferred Jena Ontology

Tags: jena, owl, ontology, jena-rules

I created an ontology based Security alerts.
After reading in some data(Individuals) it got pretty big, so I decided to use a Jena Rule Reasoner to determine some facts. I mostly give Individuals types and attributes and use some regex. Heres a small (constructed) example which gives an individual the type "multiple", when its information matches the regex:

> [testRuleContent: (?X ns:hasClassification ?Y), (?Y ns:hasText ?Z), regex(?Z, '.*Multiple.*')
>   -> (?X rdf:type ns:Multiple)]

To use the reasoner i create an infModel based on my previous loaded ontology:

```
RuleReasoner ruleReasoner = new RuleReasoner("GenaralRuleReasoner");
//read rules from file
List<Rule> ruleList = Rule.parseRules(Rule.parseRules(rd));
com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.Reasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(ruleList);
//jenaOntology is the ontology with the data
InfModel inferredOntotlogy = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, jenaOntology);
inferredOntotlogy.prepare();
```

This works without a problem and i can write the infModel into a file with the added types.

Whats the preferable method to query the inferred ontology for certain individuals (in this example those with the type: "Multiple")?

At the moment I use "listStatements()" on the Inferred Model:

```
Resource multiple = inferredOntotlogy.getResource("file:/C:/ns#Multiple");
StmtIterator iter = inferredOntotlogy.listStatements(null, RDF.type, multiple);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Resource subject = iter.next().getSubject();
        //Individual ind = subject.as(Individual.class);
        String indUri = iter.next().getSubject().getURI();
```

The cast throws an exception(Its only a node with the Uri). But I get the valid Uri of the individual and could work with the basic ontology model without the new proprties (I only need them to get the searched individual so its a possible solution).

A similar attempt would be to use getDeductionsModel() on the Inferred Model to get a Model -> OntModel and query it (potentially with SPARQL).

But id prefere an easy way to query the Inferred Model. Is there such a solution? Or can u give me a tip how to handle this situaion the best way?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're having?  Working with a Resource isn't usually a problem;  is there some particular reason that you want an Individual (as opposed to just a Resource)?  You can run SPARQL queries against the InfModel, too, if you want.

Comment: You are probably right. I havent even thought about using the resource . Looking at the API an Individual only gives me listPropertyValues() which i can easily do with a resource, too. Currently im at home(EU), so i will test it tomorrow and report. TY

Comment: Its working perfectly fine with the resource. TY Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just work with the resources fow now. It provides all the functionality I need. I should have taken a closer look at the API.

I answered my own question to mark it as solved tomorrow.